# Spring Rest CXF [bean error] Tomcat

Tags: spring, rest, cxf, jax-rs, javabeans

I´m doing a webservice in rest, spring, cxf and tomcat.

Link full project: http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/99585767/file.html

I´ve got this error on bean. 
Can´t figure out why is this happening?

> `SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restContainer': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'timeService' while setting bean property 'serviceBeans' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'timeService' is defined
>
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)`

timeService.java

```
@Service("timeService")  
@Path("/time")  
public class TimeService {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getDateTime()
    {
        DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        return formatter.print(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="timeService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

These are my files and i can´t find out what is wrong. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) says that you need to add an element to direct the finding of your `@Service`-annotated beans. For example, if your beans were in the package `org.example` or one of its sub-packages, you'd use a component scanner configuration in your beans.xml like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

(As long as it's inside the `<beans>` element, it's fine whether it goes above or below the `<jaxrs:server>` element.)

Comment: For the record, I prefer to describe my beans explicitly in the beans.xml, in part because some of them are instances of classes in libraries that I've not written. YMMV.

Comment: Still gives the same error "No bean named 'timeService' is defined"

Comment: @bruno: Well that means it's not looking at the class with the annotation. There's many reasons why this could be failing, but I have no intention of debugging your entire project. Check your logs, see what it does find. (If you don't know, *turn up your logging!*) If the worst comes to the worst, fall back on explicit declaration of your beans in the beans.xml; I know for sure that works because I'm using it myself. :-)